# How to compare integer field with json field?

Tags: android, json, android-edittext

I have following json response,from this response I am getting unitprice and boxqty, 1500 and 1 in two different edittext,now what I am trying is if user will change boxqty from 1 to 15,then unit price should be change from 1500 to 1470,following is my code snippet,

```
{"status":"success","clientproduct":[{"pid":"4","name":"kangan pair","unitprice":"1500","boxqty":"1","bulkprice":[{"minqty":"10","price":"1500"},{"minqty":"15","price":"1470"},{"minqty":"20","price":"1460"}]}]}
```

MainActivity.java

```
     @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String...args) {
        //Check for success tag
        //int success;
        Looper.prepare();

         try {
             List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
             params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cid",letss));
             params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action", "clientproduct"));

             System.out.println("su gayu server ma????"+params);

             Log.d("request!", "starting");
             // getting product details by making HTTP request
             JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest (
                 FEEDBACK_URL, "POST", params);
             //check your log for json response
             Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());
            if (json != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json.toString());
                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    clientproduct = jsonObj.getJSONArray(CLIENTPRODUCT_LIST);
                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < clientproduct.length(); i++) {
                       ck = clientproduct.getJSONObject(i);
                       unitp=ck.getString("unitprice");
                        System.out.println("Unit ni price"+unitp);
                       boxq=ck.getString("boxqty");
                        System.out.println("Box ni quantity "+boxq);

                        bulkprice = ck.getJSONArray(BULKPRICE_LIST);

                        allqtys=new ArrayList<Integer>();
                         for (int b=0 ; b < bulkprice.length(); b++)
                         {
                             jo = bulkprice.getJSONObject(b);

                           minimum_qty=jo.getInt("minqty");
                        allqtys.add(minimum_qty);
                            /* allqtys=new ArrayList<String>();
                           allqtys.add(minimum_qty.toString());
                          System.out.println("All MinQuantitiy"+minimum_qty);*/
                     System.out.println("All MinQuantitiy"+allqtys);
                       System.out.println("MinQuantitiy"+minimum_qty);

                           pricess=jo.getString("price");
                            System.out.println("Box price "+pricess);

                         }
                         /*conrs=Integer.parseInt(allqtys.toString());
                         System.out.println("Integer converted arrray"+conrs);*/

                        /* newList = new ArrayList<Integer>(allqtys.size()) ;
                         for (String myInt : allqtys) 
                         { 
                           newList.add(Integer.valueOf(myInt)); 
                         }
                         System.out.println("allqtys "+newList);*/

                        System.out.println("Not Null");
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }


         return json.getString(FEEDBACK_SUCCESS);

     }catch (JSONException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     return null;
}

    // After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        //dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        pDialog.dismiss();

       /* ArrayList<Integer> allval=new ArrayList<Integer>();
       // allval.add(minimum_qty);
       System.out.println("Integer converted arraylist"+allval);*/


        autoproduct.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // uprice.setText(unitp);
                    //bxqtyy.setText(boxq);
            }
        });


        bxqtyy.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(Integer.parseInt(bxqtyy.getText().toString()) > Integer.parseInt(allqtys.get(index)))
                {
                    if(bxqtyy.getText().equals(null))
                    {
                        uprice.setText(unitp);
                    }
                    uprice.setText("1470");
                    //System.out.println("lets check");
                }
                else
                {
                    uprice.setText("1500");
                    System.out.println("lets check");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

}}
```

Comment: just covert the data type to integer.

and how is this line is working fine "if(bxqtyy.getText().toString() > minimum_qty.compareTo(BOX_QTY))" ?

Comment: no its not working if(bxqtyy.getText().toString() > minimum_qty.compareTo(BOX_QTY))

Comment: and why are you using minimum_qty.compareTo(BOX_QTY) ?

Comment: Try  Integer.parseInt(bxqtyy.getText().toString()> minimum_qty.compareTo(BOX_QTY))). but your logic of using  minimum_qty.compareTo(BOX_QTY)) is wrong I think as it will return a random integer value

Comment: @Niv then how can i compare with the integer what i enter and minqty of json

Comment: Can i Know what you actually need by the code minimum_qty.compareTo(BOX_QTY)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line `if(bxqtyy.getText().toString() > minimum_qty.compareTo(BOX_QTY))` is not working because you can't compare string with integer, specifically  ">" operator will throw compile time error.

Use this

```
Integer.parseInt(your text here);
```

and proper code for it

```
if(Integer.parseInt(bxqtyy.getText().toString()) > minimum_qty.compareTo(BOX_QTY))
    {

    }
```

hope this will help.

Comment: you have to make conditions based on it, and on behalf on conditions you will change the unitprice

Comment: if(Integer.parseInt(bxqtyy.getText().toString()) > minimum_qty.compareTo(BOX_QTY))
    {
 uprice.setText("//use your logic// l");
    }

Comment: by the way "minimum_qty.compareTo(BOX_QTY)" is a wrong logic, you must convert every string to integer before comparing them in this scenario. use Integer's compareTo instead of using String's compareTo method

Comment: i can tell you logic to implement, you have to code it yourself.

Comment: as per your logic how will i get,to which field i need to compare.so is it possible to store all the fields in arraylist and then compare edittext enter value with arraylist items??

Comment: Absolutely, store them in arraylist and compare with edittext's value.

Comment: because right now it is taking last value 20..so how to do that?

Comment: ok see my edited question now i got all the minqty in arraylist..now how to give condition?